# How to correctly use the "write" syscall on MacOS to print to stdout?

Tags: macos, assembly, x86-64, system-calls, gnu-assembler

I have looked at similar questions, but cannot seem to find what is wrong with my code.

I am attempting to make the "write" syscall on MacOS to print a string to standard output.

I am able to do it with `printf` perfectly, and am familiar with calling other functions in x64 assembly.

This is, however, my first attempt at a `syscall`.

I am using GCC's GAS assembler.

This is my code:

```
.section __TEXT,__text

.globl _main

_main:
    pushq %rbp
    movq %rsp, %rbp

    subq $32, %rsp

    movq $0x20000004, %rax
    movq $1, %rdi
    leaq syscall_str(%rip), %rsi
    movq $25, %rdx
    syscall

    jc error

    xorq %rax, %rax

    leave
    ret

error:
    movq $1, %rax
    leave
    ret

.section __DATA,__data
syscall_str:
    .asciz "Printed with a syscall.\n"
```

There does not seem to be any error; there is simply nothing written to `stdout`.

I know that `start` is usually used as the starting point for an executable on MacOS, but it does not compile with GCC.

Comment: If it did not compile/assemble/link, there should have been an error message.  What was it?

Comment: @fuz it does compile, but when I run it, nothing is written to `stdout`

Comment: @fuz if you're referring to the compilation error when trying to compile with `start` as the entry point, it is: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Comment: I think `movq $0x20000004, %rax` should be `movq $0x2000004, %rax` (one less 0)

Comment: @GregorHartlWatters Try to link with `-nostdlib -nostartfiles`.

Comment: @GregorHartlWatters Also try to use `dtruss` to trace the system calls of the program.

Comment: @MichaelPetch aghhhhh!!!! YES!!!! That was it!!!! Thank you so much! 2 has to be shifted left by 24 bits (`2 << 24`) and not by 28 which is what I was effectively doing. If you make your comment into an answer I would happily accept it. Thanks again

Comment: @fuz thanks for the suggestions, I will look into them. and merry christmas!

Comment: @GregorHartlWatters : I have amended Javadİbrahimli answer to explicit state what your error was. You can accept that answer. Happy holidays!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are using the incorrect SYSCALL number for MacOS. The base for the user system calls is 0x2000000. You are incorrectly using that base. As a result you have encoded the `write` SYSCALL as `$0x20000004` when it should have been `$0x2000004` (one less zero)

As a rule of thumb, make sure you are using the correct value for the SYSCALL number in the `%rax` register; ensure you are using the correct arguments for the `write` SYSCALL. The `write` SYSCALL expects the following arguments:

- `%rdi`: file descriptor to write to (e.g. 1 for standard output)
- `%rsi`: pointer to the buffer containing the data to be written
- `%rdx`: number of bytes to be written
- On macOS, you need to use the `syscall` instruction to invoke a system call.